# Sumar fila en base a sus hijos

Tags: javascript, html

Debo realizar la siguiente sumatoria por línea. Es un poco complicada pero debo sumar cuando es un Ítem Padre.

Ejemplo: el ítem 3.2 es un padre, entonces debo sumar sus hijos *cantidad * precio igual el ítem 3*.

**3.2.1=> 3 * 0.002731725 = 0.008195175**

**3.2.2=> 2 * 0.0026412   = 0.0052824**

**Total padre 3.2         = 0.013477575**

Tengo una función en JS cuando encuentre algo similar lo sume al ítem. **Debería crear un array con los atributos de la tabla y luego hacer un loop pero al revés actualizando el total**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var array_data = [];
  $("#tbl tbody > tr").each(function() {
    var row = $(this).find('td');
    var item = $.trim($(row[1]).text());
    var cantidad = $.trim($(row[2]).text());
    var precio = $.trim($(row[3]).text());
    var is_father = $.trim($(row[4]).text());
    array_data.push({
      "item": item,
      "cantidad": cantidad,
      "precio": precio,
      "is_father": is_father,
      "new_precio": 0,
    });
  });
  $.each(array_data.reverse(), function(k, v) {
    if (v.is_father == 'Si') {
      v.new_precio = sumar_hijos(v.item);
    } else {
      v.new_precio = v.precio;
    }
  });

  $.each(array_data, function(k, x) {
    console.log(x.item +" precio "+ x.new_precio)
  });
});

function sumar_hijos(this_item) {
  var suma = 0;
  $("#tbl tbody > tr").each(function() {
    var row = $(this).find('td');
    var item = $.trim($(row[1]).text());
    var cantidad = $.trim($(row[2]).text());
    var precio = $.trim($(row[3]).text());
   if (item.includes(this_item) && item != this_item) {
      suma += cantidad * precio;
    }

  });
  return suma
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="table-responsive text-nowrap">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tbl">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Articulo </th>
        <th>Item </th>
        <th>Cantidad</th>
        <th>Precio </th>
        <th>is_padre </th>
        <th>Total </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody_folio">
      <tr>
        <td>PISOCK2080-2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>0.00034272 </td>
        <td>No</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>PISOCK2080-3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>0.022179</td>
        <td>Si</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>PISOCK2080-3.1</td>
        <td>3.1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>0.0035828 </td>
        <td>No</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>PISOCK2080-3.2</td>
        <td>3.2</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0.0122739</td>
        <td>Si</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>PISOCK2080-3.2.1</td>
        <td>3.2.1</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>0.002731725</td>
        <td>No</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>PISOCK2080-3.2.2</td>
        <td>3.2.2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>0.0026412 </td>
        <td>No</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Algo así debería quedar la tabla

| Articulo | Item | Cantidad | Precio | is_padre | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PISOCK2080-N | 1 | 7 | 0.00853944 | No | 0.00853944 |
| PISOCK20105-N | 2 | 2 | 0.00034272 | No | 0.00034272 |
| PISOCK2080-N | 3 | 2 | 0.022179 | Si | 0.020643175 |
| PISOCK20105-N | 3.1 | 2 | 0.0035828 | No | 0.0035828 |
| PISOCK2080-N | 3.2 | 1 | 0.0122739 | Si | 0.013477575 |
| PISOCK20105-N | 3.2.1 | 3 | 0.002731725 | No | 0.002731725 |
| PISOCK20105-N | 3.2.2 | 2 | 0.0026412 | No | 0.0026412 |
|  |  |  |  |  | 0.051958635 |

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas usar expresiones regulares para comparar cadenas.  Intenta usar `.includes()` para comparar asi:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tbl tbody > tr").each(function() {
    var row = $(this).find('td');
    var item = $.trim($(row[1]).text());
    var precio = $.trim($(row[3]).text());
    var is_father = $.trim($(row[4]).text());

    if (is_father == 'Si') {
      $(row[5]).text(sumar_hijos(item));
    } else {
      $(row[5]).text(precio);
    }

  });
});

function sumar_hijos(this_item) {
  var suma = 0;
  var test = this_item;
  $("#tbl tbody > tr").each(function() {
    var row = $(this).find('td');
    var item = $.trim($(row[1]).text());
    var cantidad = $.trim($(row[2]).text());
    var precio = $.trim($(row[3]).text());
    if (item.includes(this_item) && item != this_item) {
      suma += cantidad * precio;
    }

  });
  return suma
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="table-responsive text-nowrap">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tbl">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Articulo </th>
        <th>Item </th>
        <th>Cantidad</th>
        <th>Precio </th>
        <th>is_padre </th>
        <th>Total </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody_folio">
      <tr>
        <td>PISOCK2080-2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>0.00034272 </td>
        <td>No</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>PISOCK2080-3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>0.022179</td>
        <td>Si</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>PISOCK2080-3.1</td>
        <td>3.1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>0.0035828 </td>
        <td>No</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>PISOCK2080-3.2</td>
        <td>3.2</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0.0122739</td>
        <td>Si</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>PISOCK2080-3.2.1</td>
        <td>3.2.1</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>0.002731725</td>
        <td>No</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>PISOCK2080-3.2.2</td>
        <td>3.2.2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>0.0026412 </td>
        <td>No</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta 
Pero el item `3.2` la  suma debe ser 0.013477575

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta.

Comment: Casi perfecto! Pero al hacer la suma del Item `3` este debe ser `0.020643175`.
Yo edite mi codigo tambien donde realizo un loop reverse

Comment: Para el item 3 debes sumar el item `3.1` y `3.2`, pero como el item `3.2` es padre asi que debes realizar el calculo primero por ahi
Me imagino hacer un loop al revez que inicie de abajo y actualizar la tabla, pero que solamente me sume los `3.1` y `3.2` al llegar al item `3`